# Getting a corrupted XLSX file when writing it to Response.OutputStream

Tags: asp.net, memorystream, npoi

In ASP.Net, I'm using NPOI to write save to an Excel doc and I've just moved to version 2+. It worked fine writing to xls but switching to xlsx is a little more challenging. My new and improved code is adding lots of NUL characters to the output file.

The result is that Excel complains that there is "a problem with some content" and do I want them to try to recover?

Here is a pic of the xlsx file that was created from my Hex editor:
[BadXlsxHexImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwqip.jpg) Those 00s go on for several pages. I literally deleted those in the editor until the file opened without an error.

Why does this code add so many NULs to this file??

```
using (var exportData = new MemoryStream())
{
     workbook.Write(exportData);
     byte[] buf = exportData.GetBuffer();

     string saveAsFileName = sFileName + ".xlsx";

     Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
     Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}; size={1}", saveAsFileName, buf.Length.ToString()));
     Response.Clear();
     Response.OutputStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
     exportData.Close();
     Response.BufferOutput = true;
     Response.Flush();
     Response.Close();
}
```

(I've already tried `BinaryWrite` in place of `OutputStream.Write`, `Response.End` in place of `Response.Close`, and setting `Content-Length` with the length of the buffer. Also, none of this was an issue writing to xls.)

Comment: in case you want to use another lib, here is one of the best I think to create xlsx: https://epplus.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are getting a bunch of null bytes is because you are using [`GetBuffer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer(v=vs.110).aspx) on the `MemoryStream`.  This will return the entire allocated internal buffer array, which will include unused bytes that are beyond the end of the data if the buffer is not completely full.  If you want to get just the data in the buffer (which you definitely do), then you should use [`ToArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

That being said, why are you writing to a `MemoryStream` at all?  You already have a stream to write to: the `OutputStream`.  Just write the workbook directly to that.

Try it like this:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", saveAsFileName));
workbook.Write(Response.OutputStream);
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
```

Comment: Nice catch about using the `OutputStream`. That change cleared it up perfectly! I expected `GetBuffer` to handle the trimming, but it's good to know that it actually gets the buffer rather than being helpful behind the scenes.

Comment: This code is called from the Page_Load event in a download.aspx. Firefox & IE handle it fine, but Chrome continues to process the HTML in the page and appends that to the buffer.

Should this code be revised to account for that? Maybe ending the `OutputStream`? (I tried `OutputStream.End()` but it didn't help.)